# Case insensitive accent devexpress filter gridview c#

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using devexpress 19.1.

When filter I want to not consider the accent, whenever I enter with `á` or `a` will display all records:

Image with accent:

[image: ImageWithAccent]

Image w/o accent:

[image: ImageWithNotAccent]

Comment: Please refer link https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e3148/custom-gridcontrol-how-to-implement-your-own-logic-for-filtering-data-in-an-auto-filter

Comment: I already read this link, and the link of examples are broken.

Comment: This example is available on GitHub: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/custom-gridcontrol-how-to-implement-your-own-logic-for-filtering-data-in-an-auto-filter-row-e3148. However, it is not about case/accent-insensitive filtering.

Answer (score 0):

From [Support Center](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T356480)

You can create a custom function that removes all diacritic symbols from the specified string and use the [GridView.SubstituteFilter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SubstituteFiltertopic) event to inject this function into the active grid filter. This approach is demonstrated in the following example: [How to make the auto filter row's filter accent insensitive](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-make-the-auto-filter-rows-filter-accent-insensitive-e5021).